# What is the difference between .= and += in PHP?

Tags: php

What are the differences between .= and += in PHP?

Comment: silly question... I know.  My brain lapsed... lol

Comment: Just learning PHP, this is a good question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Quite simply, "+=" is a numeric operator and ".=" is a string operator. Consider this example:

```
$a = 'this is a ';
$a += 'test';
```

This is like writing:

```
$a = 'this' + 'test';
```

The "+" or "+=" operator first converts the values to integers (and all strings evaluate to zero when cast to ints) and then adds them, so you get 0.

If you do this:

```
$a = 10;
$a .= 5;
```

This is the same as writing:

```
$a = 10 . 5;
```

Since the "." operator is a string operator, it first converts the values to strings; and since "." means "concatenate," the result is the string "105".

Answer (score 11):

The `.` operator is the string concatenation operator.  `.=` will concatenate strings.

The `+` operator is the addition operator.  `+=` will add numeric values.

Answer (score 9):

.= is concatenation, += is addition

Answer (score 2):

. is for string concatenation and + is for addition.

.= would append something to a string while += will add something to something.

Answer (score 1):

.= is string concatenation.

+= is value addition.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference `.=` is string concatenation while `+=` is value addition.